# about inbound and outbound bandwidth

Tags: internet

how do i check my available inbound and outbound bandwidth? What is influencing them?
Thank you for your support!!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how do you check the bandwidth being used, you can check it by using the monitoring tools available on your edge router. These vary by brand.

If you mean how do you check what it is, you should consult your SLA with your ISP.

The inbound and outbound traffic on your network influences your available bandwidth.